# Fractal geometry: Is A+1 compact if A is a nonempty compact set?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, real-algebraic-geometry

Define: Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $\mathscr H$ be the collection subset of X other than the empty set.

Define: Let $(X,d)$ be a matric space and $S\subset C$. For $\epsilon\ge0$, define $$S+\epsilon:=\{y\in X\;|\; d(x,y)\le\epsilon\  for\ some\ x\in S \}$$

Here comes my question,

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A\in\mathscr H(X)$. Is $A+1$ always compact?

I think it's yes, because I think $A+1$ has no big difference with $A$. But I don't know how to prove it.

Am I wrong? please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(X,d)$ be the space $[0,1[$ with the usual distance. Whatever may be your definition of $\mathscr H$ (non empty *compact* sets or just non empty sets) the set $A = \{0\}$ is compact, and $A + 1 = X$ is not compact.

Comment: A={0} is not compact in (X,d), right?
but I can let X=[0,2] and A={1}, then A+1=X is not compact.
is that allright?

Comment: A topological $X$ space is compact if it is Hausdorff and if every open cover has a finite subcover. The latter condition is intrinsic, that is, if $Y$ is a subset of $X$, and if $Y$ is compact, then any cover of $Y$ by open sets of $X$ has also a finite subcover, and reciprocally, if any cover of $Y$ by open sets of $X$ has a finite subcover, then any cover of $Y$ by open sets in $Y$ has a finite sub-cover. Anyway, intuitively, there is no way for $A = \{0\}$ not to be compact...

Comment: more question, why X is not compact?

Comment: because U(1/n,n)is an open cover but there is no finite subcover

Thank you, I finally figure out.

Comment: You're wrong, $(]1/n,n[)_n$ is not an open cover of $[0,1[$ as no set contains $0$... The cover $([0,1-1/n[)_n$ is an open cover, and does not contain any finite subcover. *This* shows that $[0,1[$ is not compact.

Comment: but if U(]1/n,n[) doesn't contain 0, then is that means U([0,1-1/n[) doesn't contain 1?

Comment: You don't care about $1$ as $1$ is not even in $X$...

Comment: oh, haha, sorry I missed that.